# How can I create a drop shadow like floating effect around a canvas component in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, shadow

I want create a drop shadow around the canvas component in flex. Technically speaking it will not be a shadow, as I want it to wrap around the component giving the component a floating look. I may be able to do it with glow, but can anyone drop an line or two who has already done it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually solved it by doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
        width="780" height="100%" borderStyle="solid" borderColor="gray"
            creationComplete="init();" backgroundColor="white">

  <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.styles.StyleManager;


            private function init():void {
                var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
                glow.color = StyleManager.getColorName("gray");
                glow.alpha = 0.8;
                glow.blurX = 4;
                glow.blurY = 4;
                glow.strength = 6;
                glow.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;

                this.filters = [glow];
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>



</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: I found this useful, too. Thnaks.

Comment: **Willtriv** is using the proper Flex method, there was no reason to put this into an AS3 Script. Just put these glow property values in his MXML example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DropShadowFilter` but it looks to be more or less the same thing:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    width="780" height="100%" borderStyle="solid" borderColor="gray"
    creationComplete="init();" backgroundColor="white" dropShadowEnabled="true">
    <mx:filters>
        <mx:DropShadowFilter
            quality="1"
            color="gray"
            alpha="0.8"
            distance="0"
            blurX="4"
            blurY="4"
            strength="6"
        />
    </mx:filters>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

In flex 4 I'm using the following. I just wanted to post this because filters property should look like below in the image. (yes I know I'm using a spark filter on an mx object)

```
 <fx:Declarations>
    <s:GlowFilter
        id="glowBlack"
        alpha=".6"
        color="0x000000"
        inner="false"
        blurX="10"
        blurY="10"
        quality = "2"

        />
```

```
             <mx:Image id="rssIcon"
              height="70"
              filters="{[glowBlack]}"
              source="assets/rss/icon_rss.png"
              styleName="rssIconStyle"
              width="70"
              scaleContent="true"
              click="openRssSite(event)"
              "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define it outside of the canvas, you can do this:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
        width="780" height="100%">

   <mx:Canvas filters="[dropShadow]" width="200" height="200" backgroundColor="white"/>
   <mx:DropShadowFilter id="dropShadow" distance="0"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with [degrafa](http://www.degrafa.com/) and skinning. Their docs are limited but you can watch one of the tutorial videos for how to create skins. Or look at their sample code. Just assign a degrafa programmatic skin to the border of your canvas and you can add all sorts of funky gradients, paths, shapes, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you might be able to get away with:

```
<mx:Canvas ... dropShadowEnabled="true" shadowDirection="right">
```

There are caveats .. outlined [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_11.html)